# Passing parameters to package run by sp_startjob

Tags: asp.net, ssis, sql-agent-job

We have an SSIS package that is run via a SQLAgent job.  We are initiating the job (via sp_startjob) from within an ASP.NET web page.  The user that is logged onto the UI needs to be logged with the SSIS package that the user initiates - hence we require the userId to be passed to the SSIS package.  The issue is we cannot pass parameters to sp_startjob.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved and/or know of an alternative to the above approach

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done through sp_startjob. You can't pass a parameter to a job step so that option is out.

If you have no concern about concurrency, and given that you can't have the same job running at the same time, you could probably hack it by changing your job step from type SQL Server Integration Services to something like a OS Command. Have the OS Command called a batch script that the web page creates/modifies. Net result being you start your package like `dtexec.exe /file MyPackage /Set \Package.Variables[User::DomainUser].Properties[Value];\"Domain\MyUser\"` At this point, the variable DomainUser in your package would have the value of Domain\MyUser.

I don't know your requirements so perhaps you can just call into the .NET framework and start your package from the web page. Although you'd probably want to make sure that call asynchronously. Otherwise unless your SSIS package is very fast, the users might try and navigate away, spam refresh etc waiting for it to the page to "work".

All of this by the way is simply pushing a value into an SSIS package. In this case, a user name. It doesn't pass along their credentials so calls to things like `SYSTEM_USER` would report the SQL Agent user account (or the operator of the job step).

Comment: Thanks for the reply billinkc - the concurrency issue kinda rules the batch file solution - after considering a few other options  we're going to go with a WCF service that will be initiated from the UI that will be deployed onto the app server (which hosts SSIS)